# Table with big data add scroll-x and change width of page

Tags: html, css, scroll, html-table, horizontal-scrolling

I upload data in table using ajax. so when I received response - data will be filled to table and it will be visible on the screen. when data contain some small text example it looks ok. but if I upload file with 40 records which contains full text then width of screen increases in few times, scroll-x is going visible but it looks like table and huge empty space on screen.

[image]

I've checked all text and data in table. everything is inside table. someone know what can be the reason of problem?

I can fix this if add property overflow-x: hidden; on my div that wrap table. but this solution really bad)
It works the same on Chrome and Mozila

```
<div id="trainData" style="display: none" class="my-table">
    <table class="table table-striped" id="trainTable">
        <thead class="thead-inverse-blue">
            <th class="inputText" >Input</th>
            <th data-field="comment" >Comment</th>
        </thead>
    </table>
</div>

.table{
margin-top: 10px;
table-layout: fixed;
width: 100%;
margin-bottom: 0 !important;
border-bottom: 1px solid #dddddd;
border-collapse: collapse !important;
border-radius: 1px;
}
.table > tbody > tr > td {
width: 1px;
white-space: pre-wrap;
word-wrap: break-word;
}
.fresh-table .table > tbody > tr > td >content{
  text-overflow:ellipsis;
  overflow:hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in decision to add white-space: pre-wrap; property. It occur scrolling and huge width. Changed to **white-space: pre-line;** and problem missed :)